# Problem with the data of an axe in a graph

Tags: graph, qlikview

I have build a graph in qlikview with the data, all the nessacery has been done but the data of the orizental axe are confused.[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you what is the problem actually can you be more specific? Is the problem sorting the x dimension? Or how it looks?

Comment: It has been solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please click chart properties go to "axes" tab and select vertical labels for primary dimension.

[image]